# Storing a single value query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I'm having a problem in storing the query result it is just a single value. Here's the code:

```
$result = $query = $this -> db -> query("SELECT MAX(Product_ID) from products") -> row() -> Product_ID;
```

And here's the error:

> A PHP Error was encounter Severity: Notice  Message: Undefined
>   property: stdClass::$Product_ID Line Number: 54

What could be the problem?

Comment: Make sure you have the `Product_ID` column in your table or Show us the result array.

Comment: I do have the `Product_ID`. I also tried to change the `row()` to `result()` and `result_array` but it has an error `Message: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: If you change the line to `$this->db->query("SELECT MAX(Product_ID) from products")->result_array()` then the worst case scenario would be that you get an empty array. If you want to get a column value from a result array btw, you need to treat it like an associative array, `$result[0]['Product_ID']`, not like an object, `$result->Product_ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When applying any MySQL function to any column, you should also add an `alias` to it since you won't get the result of the column using the column name itself. Try below,

```
$result = $query = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(Product_ID) as Product_ID from products")->row()->Product_ID;
```

Or a more **better way**,

```
$this->db->select('MAX(Product_ID) as Product_ID');
$this->db->from('products');
$result = $query = $this->db->get()->row()->Product_ID;
```

Comment: Reason: since you were using `MAX(Product_ID)` now your column name changes to `MAX(Product_ID)` and not `Product_ID`.